# How do you pan on a mac?

Tags: interface

Beginner here! How do you pan around the screen on a mac? I've tried clicking "emulating 3-button mouse" but it still doesn't work with the two-finger scroll on the laptop trackpad.

I'm also using a wireless mac mouse.

Comment: ALT + Left Mouse

Comment: get a 3 mutton mouse. you wont regret it.

Comment: ALT + left doesn't work either :/ Looks like I'll have to pick up a 3 button mouse!

Comment: SHIFT + ALT + Left Mouse Button.

Comment: If you have trouble with the previous answers , watch this video. (Only if you had trouble)
https://youtu.be/70RORPiCsh8

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + two finger scroll around. **You don't need a three-button mouse**, as Blender has excellent multi-touch trackpad* support. (You can two-finger scroll to orbit around, and pinch to zoom, too! It even supports horizontal scrolling of header regions/tab bars.)

<sub>*Or a Magic Mouse, which is basically a mouse with a trackpad on top. Never actually tried one with Blender, though.</sub>

Comment: Yes, this is correct, however, you definitely *want* a three button mouse. Everything is just so much faster that way. I went without for almost a year and thoroughly regret it.

Comment: @duhaime That's odd, I have Select With > Left, and it still works fine. Are you on Mac OS X, or some other OS? If you're not on Mac, your trackpad support may be different.

Comment: Ah you're quite right! It must have been some other config I changed that enabled this (or rather prevented this from being disabled). I'll delete my earlier comment...

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and slide your finger on the magic mouse in the direction you want to pan.  Hold <kbd>Control</kbd> and slide your finger to zoom in/out.

Comment: The Magic Mouse doesn't have a scroll wheel—it's basically a mouse with a trackpad on top.

Comment: well... you get what i mean :D

Comment: Well, some people might not—they'd  be left staring at the blank white surface going "he said there's a wheel...where _is_ it?" (:   Also, when you Ctrl+scroll, it zooms the whole screen in and out. (Not sure if it's turned on by default, though).

Comment: Hehe yeah... The scrolling in and out is a default thing

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a minute. I have Blender 3.5.0 and Emulate 3-button mouse turned on. I also strictly use the Magic Mouse and to accomplish this, I needed to click `Shift`+ `Option(Alt)` + `Click`

Hope this helps someone else!